# Android remove localizations

Tags: android, localization, google-play, apk, android-appcompat

My app at Play Store does not have any localizations other than the default: *English (United States)*. This time I created a new apk to update it. And it uses *android-support-v7-appcompat* library. So when I uploaded the new apk and in the apk details it says 'added 72 new localizations'. These are coming from the values folders in *android-support-v7-appcompat* (values-af, values-am,...etc).

Is this okay or if not, how do I remove the localizations? 
My app has just one values folder and I do not want to add localizations.

Comment: +1, I even try to remove all the `values` folders of my app, disable ProGuard, and zipalign and the result is still the same. Lucky I came across your question! (Wasted a few hours on this) http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc4LJ.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry about it: the message is only seen to you as a developer and not seen by any user. The only clue that you'd support a different language is if you [translated your Google Play store listing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3125566?hl=en). AppCompat strings are solely used for content descriptions used for accessibility systems such as [Talkback](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.marvin.talkback) so they won't be visible to the vast majority of users of your app.

Answer (score 9):

In build.gradle, add resConfigs to limit the languages:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // other configuration here
        resConfigs "en"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also using the support libraries but with this gradle setup, 
I could make my apk smaller by 12%. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AshokVarma Thank you! A good article explaining this: https://medium.com/google-developers/smallerapk-part-3-removing-unused-resources-1511f9e3f761#.rm5n4kdui.